# Relatórios em uma aplicação web

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, relatório

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e estou precisando de uma ajuda na geração de relatórios , sou novo e não sei qual a melhor ferramenta para geração de relatórios, se e por meio de um Framework , bibliotecas em angula-JS,JavaScript ou java; com sou novato na área gostaria de saber qual a melhor pratica e ferramentas para implementar relatórios, meu projeto possui as seguintes tecnologias
, Spring-Boot , Spring-Securit , Java , Angular-js , jquery , HTML5 e Hibernate.

Comment: Relatorio? a partir do que? de onde? seja mais expecifico por favor

Comment: poderia ser tanto no back-end quanto no font-end; mais como sou novo e com pouca experiencia gostaria de saber a melhor maneira de implementar. Uma dica de quem tem mais experiencia. Vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Nao existe algo especifico, voce pode usar PHP (ou qualquer linguagem de Back-End), e tambem consegue fazer isso do lado do Front. Tipo Javascript. Basta escolher e ver qual voce é melhor.

Comment: Cara, você pode usar praticamente qualquer coisa. Isso depende muito do projeto no que você está atuando e das suas habilidades com esse tipo de coisa. Do jeito que está, a sua pergunta é muito genérica, abrangente e opinativa.

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Aqui na minha empresa, desenvolvemos um sistema ERP bem complexo. Parte desse sistema é muito rica em relatórios dos mais variados graus de complexidade de informações. A ferramenta que nós escolhemos para utulizar na criação e geração de relatórios foi o Birt. Não sei se erá muito util pra você, pois aqui na empresa as clases que interagem com o Birt são todas em PHP, trata-se do nosso backend.
O Birt tem alguns problemas chatinhos, como mudar a conexão do banco que ele vai consultar para gerar o relatório e tudo mais, mas nada que inutilize a ferramenta.

Nesse link você encontra as informações básicas da ferramenta:

[BIRT Home](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/)

Vale ressaltar que o Birt é uma ferramente até que bem difundida, e por esse motivo você encontra soluções de problemas, dicas e tutoriais sem muita dificuldade.

Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte!